# finding chars distance in StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I need to write code which should find distance of chars. I think i would better explain in example.

I have String Builder like this:

**BANSANA**

I should take first letter B and find distance to other B letter. However in BANANA there isn't other B so i write in in S (for example Array List) 1.

So my list now look like this:

**S={"1"}**

Then i need to take other letter and find it's distance, so i take A and distance to other A is 2.

My S look like this:

**S={"1","2"}**

So algorithm is repeated till the end.

Maybe someone had done this task and could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, please first post what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hava a look at this fragment:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("BANANA");
int first = sb.indexOf("A");
int second = sb.indexOf("A", first+1);
int distance = second - first;
```